# Trying to get Mandrill to send an email (codecademy exercise)

Tags: javascript, api, mandrill

I'm trying to learn how to use the API's and I stumbled upon codecademy's [course](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-intermediate-en-hwulM/1/1?curriculum_id=5122e6f8b2cb8a8e97000a01#) and I'm doing their Mandrill API course

```
// Create a function to log the response from the Mandrill API
function log(obj) {
    $('#response').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

// create a new instance of the Mandrill class with your API key
var m = new mandrill.Mandrill('sDJw??-3FK4r1h8aH2vckw');

// create a variable for the API call parameters
var params = {
    "message": {
        "from_email":"jack??@yahoo.com",
        "to":[{"email":"jack??@yahoo.com"}],
        "subject": "Sending a text email from the Mandrill API",
        "text": "I'm learning the Mandrill API at Codecademy."
    }
};

function sendTheMail() {
// Send the email!

    m.messages.send(params, function(res) {
        log(res);
    }, function(err) {
        log(err);
    });
}
```

The API key should work. The course allowed me to test in a previous exercise. I heard that Mandrill had changes recently that mentions

> you must add SPF and DKIM records and verify ownership of your
>   sending domains before you can send email through your account.

I'm wondering if I made mistake in the exercise or if the exercise dosen't work anymore because of the recent changes. I hope the link I showed you wasn't blocked .

Here is the error response:

```
[{"email":"jack??@yahoo.com","status":"rejected","_id":"?7ec118ce30044d493795081552c57d2","reject_reason":"unsigned"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your code. I test it using my account api key and it works fine. This is something to do on Mandrill recent changes [see here](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I cant use this to practice APIs because i would need to have a domain or website to hook this up to and I don't have one?